# multiplying two huge matrices using numpy.dot

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to multiply two huge vectors  (30720,1)* (1,30720)  so this will give a 30720*30720 matrix . I am using numpy.dot to multiply them but it is taking a very long time.

Comment: What does this have to do with C++? And a 30kx30k matrix is huge, of course it takes long to compute.

Comment: Of course this multiplication will take time. And a dedicated optimized low level routine is generally more efficient than a generic tool like numpy (even if numpy is already good at this kind op operation). That beeing said, any serious answer could be too long for SO site, so this question looks too broad for me.

Comment: Numpy uses a library like BLAS for this kind of calculation.  But memory swaps might chewing up time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `float64` data, the result size is about 7 Go, so it doesn't fit in a lot of PC RAM. But you have only 30720² # 1e9 multiplications to do, which take a few seconds.

A way to avoid the memory issues is to cut the result in reasonable chunks, with sizes < 1Go, and save the partial results in files with binary protocol for speed, with adds to control what happens :

```
n=3
div=10240
a=rand(n*div,1)
b=rand(1,n*div)
import pickle

def calculate(i,j):
    u=dot(a[i*div:(i+1)*div,:],b[:,j*div:(j+1)*div])
    return u

def save(i,j,u):
     with open('data'+str(i)+str(j)+'.pk','wb') as f :
                   pickle.dump(u,f)

def timecount(f,args):
   t0=time.time()
   res=f(*args)
   return res,time.time()-t0

def multidot():
  tcalc,tsave=0,0  
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print (i,j)
        u,dt=timecount(calculate,(i,j))
        tcalc+=dt
        _,dt=timecount(save,(i,j,u))
        tsave+=dt
  print('dot time',tcalc)
  print('save time',tsave)
```

Then the run :

```
In [64]: multidot()
 0 0
 0 1
 0 2
 1 0
 1 1
 1 2
 2 0
 2 1
 2 2
dot time 4.697121858596802
save time 29.11250686645508
```

So you have no problem with `dot`, only with memory issues.

To read back your data, read it, chunk by chunk, like that:

```
with open('data00.pk','rb') as f : u=pickle.load(f)
```

Don't forget to `del data*.pk` after this run, it takes 6Go on your disk ;)